# How to use std::atomic for registers with fixed address

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

As far as I understand it `std::atomic<uint32_t> foo` will create an atomic variable for me, but the actual memory location will be decided by the linker.
On the other hand `std::atomic<uint32_t*> bar` will create an atomic pointer, i.e. the pointer itself is protected, but not the target it points to.

I was wondering if it is also possible to create an atomic variable protecting a known memory address (e.g. a register of a device). Something like

```
uint32_t register_addr = 0xdeadbeef;
std::atomic<uint32_t> register(register_addr);
```

So that device register accesses from different threads are automatically serialized.

Comment: If you are compiling to a target with fixed addresses that have particular meanings, doesn't your compiler offer some extension to assign a particular global variable to a particular address?

Comment: @NicolBolas often one just receives a base address and then uses fixed offsets to calculate the final address at runtime.

Comment: `auto& register = *new(static_cast<void*>(register_addr)) std::atomic<uint32_t>;` Something like that, perhaps.